# Slack notifications do not work

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, notifications, slack

I have the Slack Windows app on my Windows 10 machine. I noticed that the notifications don't work properly. In 'Preferences', I click 'Send test notification', but it doesn't send one. When I had Windows 8.1 it wasn't working neither. How can this be fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I've noticed is that the notifications *are* being sent, but they appear *below* all other windows. The solution is to either restart slack or to minimize to desktop, send a test notification and then click on it.

Comment: FWIW I have the same problem and I'm just using the web based app for now.

Comment: Also, try this: http://betanews.com/2015/09/09/how-to-stop-slack-from-using-action-center-notifications-in-windows-10/

Comment: Are you using the 64-bit version of the desktop app? Does the 32-bit version work for you?

I've seen it not be a problem for Windows 7, but Windows 8/10 64-bit version has spotty notification sounds while the 32-bit version works fine in Windows 8/10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried closing and reopening Slack app after checking `Notifications` >> `Send notifications for:` >> `All activity`?

It worked for me and my colleagues.

Comment: Restarting the app worked for me as well.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 7. Good old "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"!

Answer (score 6):

Neither of the answers/comments worked for me. Will share what helped in my case (Windows 10 x64). Might help anyone else.
I had to turn off Slack's integration with Windows Action Center basically and they started to show up.

[Solution](https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/637707911796494337?lang=en):

1. Press: Win + R
2. Type: "slack://notReallyWindows10"
3. Hit: Enter

PS, I think I did this twice.

Answer (score 4):

I had quiet hours turned on in Windows. Turning it off fixed Slack's notifications. Quiet hours are only supposed to take effect from 12AM to 6AM, so I'm not sure if this is a Slack problem or Windows problem.

Comment: This was my issue 100%, I was pulling my hair out

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue. I tried the solutions listed here and it still didn't work. I ended up going into Windows Action Center settings and switched #slack notifications off, then back on and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions here worked for me. What finally did work, was going to `Help > Reset App Data`

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything here and nothing worked
Also, Slack was not in `Notifications & actions settings`

In the end I uninstalled Slack completely, then reinstalled [Slack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/slack/9wzdncrdk3wp) from the Microsoft Store. After that I could see Slack in `Notifications & actions settings` and Action Center notifications worked again.

Comment: For me, Slack was present in the notification settings, but disabled (greyed out). Uninstalling and installing from the Store also worked for me, after changing the notification settings in Slack and restarting it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had some snooze notifications turned on in Slack (a bell-symbol). Turning it off worked for me... It is supposed to be turned on automatically after office hours but Slack seemed to fail in puting me in the right time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, I had installed slack from downloading from its official website and notifications weren't working with all sorts of settings enabled. My company's IT guy told me to install it from Apple Appstore and notifications started working.